# How include two horizontal lines below and above section in scrartcl as well as "Chapter X" label?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, koma-script, titlesec, scrartcl

I am using the `scrartcl` document class in LaTeX (and I need to use this for several reasons). Now, I want to get something like this for every section:

[image]

Currently I am doing the following:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{titlerulecolor}{orange}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\scshape\raggedleft}{}{0em}
{ }[{\color{titlerulecolor}\titlerule}]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

Nonetheless, I have not figured out:

1. how to make LaTeX automatically add the Chapter X text above
2. how to add the second line
3. how to prevent this formatting to also happen in the table of contents.

Comment: Does the `scrartcl` class have chapters, contrary to `article`?

Comment: @Bernard It doesn't but I just need a easy and dirty trick to make it look like it has 

Comment: But why don't you use `scrreport`?

Comment: B.t.w., don't use `titlesec` with `komascript`.

Comment: Using `titlesec` with one of the KOMA script documentclasses will result in the following warning: "Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package titlesec together
with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
 I'd suggest to use the package only
if you really need it, because it breaks several
 KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
the extended optional argument of the section
 commands."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: do not use `titlesec` with a KOMA-Script class.

If you need chapters switch to `scrreprt`, eg:

```latex
\documentclass[
  headings=chapterprefix
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{titlerulecolor}{orange}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge\scshape}
\addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\LARGE\upshape}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=3pt,
  innerskip=0pt,
  afterskip=3pt
]{chapter}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][.4pt]{\textcolor{titlerulecolor}{\rule[.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{#1}}}
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{#2#3}{%
      \raggedleft%
      #2%
      \titlerule\\*%
      \kern-1.5ex\nobreak%
      #3\par\nobreak%
      \kern1ex\nobreak%
      \titlerule\par%
    }%
  }{#2#3}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\Blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Example with `scrartcl` and sections:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{titlerulecolor}{orange}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{section}{\Huge\scshape}
\newkomafont{sectionprefix}{\LARGE\upshape}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  afterindent=false,
  beforeskip=\dimexpr\baselineskip+3pt\relax,
  afterskip=3pt
]{section}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{Section~\thesection\autodot}

\newcommand\titlerule[1][.4pt]{\textcolor{titlerulecolor}{\rule[.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \ifstr{#3}{}{\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}{%
      \raggedleft%
      {\usekomafont{sectionprefix}#3\par\nobreak}%
      \titlerule\\*%
      \kern-1.5ex\nobreak%
      #4\par\nobreak%
      \titlerule\par\nobreak%
    }%
  }{\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\Blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I get the error ! Package scrbase Error: unknown option `afterindent=false'.
for the scrartcl. Any idea why?

Comment: `afterindent=false` needs KOMA-Script version 3.26b (current version on CTAN, in TeXLive 2018 and 2019 and in MiKTeX). If your version is older, then remove option `afterindent=false` and use `beforeskip=-3pt` in the first example and `beforeskip=\dimexpr-\baselineskip-3pt\relax` in the second example.

Comment: Thanks! Now everything works except could you point me on how to exclude the Appendix to also take on this format? And also, how can I reduce the font size in just one of the sections?

Comment: You could use  `\let\originalchapterlinesformat\chapterlinesformat` before the redefinition of `\chapterlinesformat`. Then you can patch `\appendix` to restore the original definition using `\let\chapterlinesformat\originalchapterlinesformat`. I do not understand your question regarding the font size. Maybe you have to ask a new question including a MWE.